# Error while using BeautifulSoup in Python, attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I resolve `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` when using BeautifulSoup?

below is the current code I have.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

with open('websites_mn.txt') as f:
    txtdata = f.readlines()

for raw_url in txtdata:
    raw_url = raw_url.strip('\n')
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(raw_url)
    content = url.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    table = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"journal-content-article"})
    for x in table:
        print(x.find('p').text)
```

here is the websites txt file.

```
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/24-avgusta-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-ministrom-energetiki-mongolii-n-tavinbeh?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/19-avgusta-2020-goda-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-zamestitelem-ministra-inostran?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/vsemirnye-zimnie-igry-special-noj-olimpiady-2022-goda-projdut-v-kazani?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/mezdunarodnyj-voenno-tehniceskij-forum-armia-2020-projdet-v-period-s-23-po-29-avgusta-2020-goda-na-territorii-kongressno-vystavocnogo-centra-patriot-?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/crezvycajnyj-i-polnomocnyj-posol-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizov-vstretilsa-s-ministrom-obrazovania-i-nauki-mongolii-l-cedevsuren-v-hode-be?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/10-iula-sostoalas-vstreca-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-i-ministra-inostrannyh-del-mongolii-n-enhtajv?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/prezident-rossijskoj-federacii-v-v-putin-pozdravil-prezidenta-mongolii-h-battulgu-s-nacional-nym-prazdnikom-naadam-?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/predsedatel-pravitel-stva-rossijskoj-federacii-m-v-misustin-pozdravil-prem-er-ministra-mongolii-u-hur?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/inistr-inostrannyh-del-rossijskoj-federacii-s-v-lavrov-pozdravil-ministra-inostrannyh-del-mongolii-n-enhtajvana-s-naznaceniem-i-nacional-nym-prazdniko?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
https://mongolia.mid.ru:443/en_US/novosti/-/asset_publisher/hfCjAfLBKGW0/content/pozdravlenie-crezvycajnogo-i-polnomocnogo-posla-rossijskoj-federacii-v-mongolii-i-k-azizova-s-nacional-nym-prazdnikom-mongolii-naada-1?inheritRedirect=false&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fmongolia.mid.ru%3A443%2Fen_US%2Fnovosti%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_hfCjAfLBKGW0%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1
```

Instead of printing all the p tags under div with journal-content-article, it stops because of NoneType error.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you can check if the object exists before accessing an attribute:

```
for x in table:
    if x.find('p'):  # add this check
       print(x.find('p').text)
```